# When using JQuery .val to set a select value, although the value already exists in the list, it sets it to null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

When using JQuery .val() function to set a select value that already exists in the list, it sets it to 'null' rather than the value.  I have this code:

```
$('#hybridSelect1').val('A304K205');
```

The value 'A304K205' does exist in the drop down.  When I set that code in either the script or the Google Chrome console, it returns a value of 'null' in both an alert as well as the console using:

```
$('#hybridSelect1').val();
```

If I manually set the value, as in clicking on a value in the drop down, the console as well as an alert will return that value, but if I try to set the EXACT value with code or the console it returns back to a null value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that's the *value* of an option and not the *display text* of one? `<option value="value">display text</option>`

Comment: Please paste the HTML of your select list as it exists in the DOM.

Comment: [Setting the value of a `<select>` works just fine](http://codepen.io/Pointy/pen/sLizA) so you're going to have to provide more context. Why, for example, is it called a "hybrid" select?

Comment: Jon, you were right, the value was different from the text. Thank you.  I had two selects with over 600 values each side by side and I confused the two.  Thanks again!